# How to memcpy a struct from another similar typedef'ed structure

Tags: c, struct, typedef, memcpy

1. struct DISPLAY_INFO *display_info;
2. typedef struct DISPLAY_INFO;

   DISPLAY_INFO display_info_2;

Have to copy diplay_info_2  to display_info. How can I do it using memcpy .

Comment: What problem are you having using `memcpy`?

Comment: display_info is a **pointer** to a structure, does it point to a valid memory area?

Answer (score 1):

Iff (if and only if) **display_info points to a valid memory area**, you can write

```
memcpy(display_info, &display_info_2, sizeof(DISPLAY_INFO));
```

e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct DISPLAY_INFO{
    int val;
} DISPLAY_INFO;

int main() {

    DISPLAY_INFO *display_info;

    display_info = (DISPLAY_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(DISPLAY_INFO));

    DISPLAY_INFO display_info_2; // The object to be copied
    display_info_2.val = 42;

    memcpy(display_info, &display_info_2, sizeof(DISPLAY_INFO));

    printf("%d", display_info->val);

    free(display_info);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/AUwDNw

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `*display_info = display_info_2`.